# Prevent vertical scroll when using anchors to scroll horizontally

Tags: css, scroll, anchor

I have a one-column website, sort of a social media-like, with posts below each other.
Some posts are a simple text, some are image and some of them are a gallery of images.

For this gallery of images, i only show the first picture and then have anchors pointing to other pictures that are hidden from the viewport (post itself is a flex element with overflow-x:auto and flex-wrap:nowrap and the child pictures are flex: 0 0 auto and max-width to fit my post view).

So the feed looks like this with other x's hidden, each having  with ID of said picture to do the scrolling without JS:
|X  |
|X  |
|X>|<x>|<x>|<x|
|X  |

I purposly avoid JS for this project, and gallery like this works, but whenever I click on said anchors, besides doing the horizontal scroll to desired image, it also scrolls vertically to the top of the target image.

Can I prevent the vertical jump when clicking on an achor while preserving the horizontal scroll?

Comment: Could you provide a demo / code snippet of your work so far? Using target links, you could use the `:target` css selector to change the target image's horizontal position so it appears inside your content as long as it is targeted. It will be easier to show you what I mean once there is example code to inspect and edit though.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce your problem but maybe this codepen about `:target` might still help you: https://codepen.io/ingosteinke/pen/abBaoaL ?

Comment: An alternative solution used by Avi Kohn with input and label instead of link targets: https://codepen.io/AMKohn/pen/EKJHf/

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it seems hard to build a pure CSS slider using only link targets. You could put an offset to the target image using a pseudo element `:target::before` similar to [Chris Coyier's hashtag-links-padding](https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/),

but there is also a [pure CSS image slider by Avi Kohn](https://codepen.io/AMKohn/pen/EKJHf/) based on an alternative approach using `input` and `label` to achieve a horizontal image slider without jumping scroll positions.